# SQL Server Select erroneous records that do not have a matching valid record

Tags: sql, sql-server, not-exists

We have an issue where we have 100,000 erroneous records in one of our tables. These erroneous records are easily identifiable because their primary key is only 8 digits instead of 10 digits long.

The problem I am running into is there are 2,000 valid records that have a matching erroneous record (i.e. a person has a valid address record and an erroneous address record). Because of this, I only want to select the erroneous records that do NOT have a matching valid record.

For example, a person's address record contains the person's ID along with their address type. So, a valid record has a primary key of `1234567HOM` for the person's home address. An erroneous record has a primary key of `1234567H` (please understand that the real table we have this issue with is not an address table. I am using the address table example to protect our information.)

So, I was able to select all of the Erroneous records that also have a valid record with the following SQL:

```
SELECT ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID
  FROM PERSON_ADDRESS AS ERRONEOUS
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSON_ADDRESS AS VALID
    ON LEFT(ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, 8) = LEFT(VALID.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, 8)
 WHERE LEN(VALID.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID) = 10
   AND LEN(ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID) = 8
```

This provides us with the list of 2,000 erroneous records that also have a valid record. However, what we actually need is a list of Erroneous records that do NOT have a valid record. I attempted to get them by adding `NOT EXISTS` to the code:

```
SELECT PERSON_ADDRESS_ID
  FROM PERSON_ADDRESS
 WHERE LEN(PERSON_ADDRESS_ID) = 8
   AND NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID
          FROM PERSON_ADDRESS AS ERRONEOUS
          LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSON_ADDRESS AS VALID
            ON LEFT(ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, 8) = LEFT(VALID.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, 8)
         WHERE LEN(VALID.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID) = 10
           AND LEN(ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID) = 8
       )
```

Unfortunately this provides me with absolutely no records. If I change the "AND NOT EXISTS" to "AND EXISTS", I get all 100,000 of my erroneous records, including the 2,000 records I don't want.

Does anyone know how I can select all of my erroneous records that do not have a valid record?

EDIT

Clarification of Question: There is only one Person_Address table, which contains both erroneous and valid records. I am selecting the same Person_Address table twice, just giving it different names because I want to find the erroneous records that do not correspond with valid records.

For example, John Smith has two address records, 1234567HOM (this is a valid record) and 1234567H (this is an erroneous record). Judith Roger has only one valid record, 2222222HOM. Seth Adams has only one erroneous record, 3333333H. I want to create a query that will only retrieve Seth Adams' record.

So even though John Smith has an erroneous record, I do not want to retrieve his erroneous record because he also has a valid record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the records that don't match the address table.  Try this:

```
SELECT ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID
FROM PERSON_ADDRESS ERRONEOUS LEFT OUTER JOIN
     PERSON_ADDRESS VALID
     ON LEFT(ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, 8) = LEFT(VALID.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID, 8) and
        ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID <> VALID.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID
WHERE valid.Person_Address_Id is null and
     LEN(ERRONEOUS.PERSON_ADDRESS_ID) = 8
```

The problem with your queries is that you had the address table in the `where` clause.  That undoes the effect of the `left outer join`.  Also, I added into the join so that valid record id is not the same as the erroneous one.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, however unfortunately that query returns zero results.

Comment: @trice . . . I think the issue is in your data.  If this is not producing results, then all 8-character person address ids are present in the valid table.

Comment: I think my question may have been slightly confusing. Please let me clarify. There is only one Person_Address table, which contains both erroneous and valid records. I was selecting the same Person_Address table twice, just giving it different names because I wanted to find the erroneous records that did not correspond with valid records.

For example, John Smith has two address records, 1234567HOM and 1234567H. Judith Roger has only one valid record, 2222222HOM. Seth Adams has only one erroneous record, 3333333H. I want to create a query that will only retrieve Seth Adams' record.

Comment: @trice . . . That clarification helps a lot.  See the revised query.